# How to fail the build when there is new uncovered code?

Tags: java, code-coverage

Do any code coverage tools for Java allow you to cause the build to fail when new uncovered code gets introduced? I don't want to fail the build based on an arbitrary cutoff like 80% because in a large codebase, the actual coverage percentage rarely fluctuates. Also if coverage falls by 0.1% it's hard to tell which are the new uncovered lines.

**EDIT**

I'm convinced not to fail the build. The other part of the question still stands. How can I find only the uncovered code that was recently checked in?

Comment: If you do this, developers will create silly unit tests just to get their code checked in, and then you won't be able to tell which code is *truly* covered. Leave it alone, and you'll be able to tell which code needs attention.

Comment: Obligatory TDWTF reference: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Thats-One-Way-to-Fulfill-a-Requirement.aspx

Comment: Finding the uncovered code is likely to depend heavily on your coverage tool. What tools are you using for coverage and continuous integration?

Comment: @erickson I'm experimenting with Clover. I'm willing to switch.

Comment: @Motlin: What exactly do you want back?  A list of files containing uncovered code?  Methods? Lines?

Comment: @Ira A list of uncovered lines that were either covered or not present in the last build.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a continuous integration server such as Hudson, you can delegate this requirement to a new job which is dependent on the build (which runs during each commit, say).

Create a script which runs your code coverage profile, and fails based on a metric. Include a wget or cURL retrieval of the previous build's code coverage percent, parsed out, if you want to use an automatic metric.

Answer (score 0):

Hudson cobertura plugin let you to rise build warnings and the native "changes" view will tell you what is the new code that do not have coverage